# Multiplication and significant figures

Tags: conventions, error-analysis

What is point of rounding off to significant figures in multiplication.
e.g. $3\times123456789=370370367$, if I round off the answer to least sig fig it becomes $400000000$ which has a large error. So what is point of significant figures here?

I really don't understand the importance of sig fig.

Comment: No rounding in the example you give: the product of two integers is an integer.

Comment: @EdV What is the indication that they are integers?

Comment: @M.Enns There is no indication they are not integers. If the 3 was supposed to have only one significant digit, therefore not be an integer, then it would either be expressed in scientific notation or as “3.”. Note the decimal point after the 3. If the number was supposed to have two sig figs, then either scientific notation, which always works, or it would be “3.0”. And so on: 3.00 or 3.000 or trailing zeroes as valid. The whole significant figures thing is problematic because a single numerical value can’t properly convey both a best value and an uncertainty range. It is ultimately flawed.

Comment: Significant figures are a waste of time. It is much easier and cleaner to simply report the absolute uncertainty and use error propagation to report the uncertainty of results of multiplication.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Yep! And some physicists are not at all bashful about spending 100 pages or so pounding that home: https://www.av8n.com/physics/uncertainty.htm. I like where Denker says “People who care about their data don’t use sig figs.”.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Soft disagree. The “significant figures” approach is a useful introduction to the idea of finite-precision data at the high-school level. Compare to the oversimplified model in intro biology courses where brown eyes and blue eyes are used to teach about dominant and recessive genes, even though eye color is a complex phenotype controlled by the interactions of many different genes. For people who haven’t yet internalized calculus, error propagation is a dark art.

Comment: @rob no need to teach full error propagation. It's just as well to teach (even as a point of memorization) that if $c = a + b$ that $\delta c = \delta a + \delta b$ and if $c = ab$ that $\delta c = a \delta b + b \delta a$. This gets you as far as broken sig fig analysis does anyways.

Comment: @Jagerber48 I teach significant figures so that my students include one untrustworthy digit in their results (or two if they are cautious about “guard digits”). Your approximation would have students systematically throw away useful information, because you have chosen not to add the uncertainties in quadrature. Which approach is less wrong is a question of teaching philosophy which doesn’t really fit into a comment debate (but it might work as an answer to this question).

Comment: @Jagerber48 Have you actually done this though? I think you're forgetting what it's like to be a high school student. High school students have trouble remembering significant digits (one simple rule that you can justify to them at their level), let alone memorizing error propagation rules (several equations that seem to come out of nowhere and that they won't have a basis to understand for a few years). It's not going to stick.

Comment: Fair point about not adding error in quadrature. It's true the formulas become more complicated when you do that. *shrug* sig figs never made sense to me when I first learned them and I always found the rules hard to look up or justify when I was trying to understand further. Error propagation always made sense to me (though I learned it much later after I knew calculus). I agree with the points made in the nice page linked above that learning sig figs just confuses the matter of proper uncertainty handling and makes it harder to learn down the road.

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 8):

I like to teach my students to trust their hunches about significant figures using their emotional response to the rounded number. I call this the “anger management method of error estimation.”

When I go hiking, I like to scrounge up a walking stick from the deadwood in the forest.  The right length for a walking stick is pretty close to my height.  I am (to one significant figure) about two meters tall.  One meter is too short for a walking stick (that’s more like a cane, which serves a different purpose).  If you imagine coming across a hiker with a three-meter walking stick, you will probably set yourself to laughing — an emotional response.

If you found two candidate walking sticks whose lengths were different by 20 cm, you might stand them up next to yourself and decide that one is a better length than the other. You might even break off a handspan (10 cm) or two to get the length right.  But imagine coming across a hiker who has heard somewhere that a walking stick should be as long as he is tall, and he was 181.5 cm tall at his last doctor visit, so he is sitting on the trail with a measuring tape carefully sanding down the knob at the top of his piece of found deadwood.  You’d probably have an emotional response to him, too.

So for the length of a walking stick, you really care about the first digit.  You probably also care about the second digit.  That last centimeter of length, through, is insignificant.  The length of a walking stick has about two significant digits.

The trousers I wore yesterday are 110 cm long.  (Two meters: not trousers. Half a meter: also not trousers.)  If you buy trousers from a fancy shop, the tailor may fuss about the last centimeter of their length, which controls how the cuff folds where it lands at your shoe.  If you have a tailor fixing the hem of your trousers, he’ll mark the correct length with a piece of chalk and then pin the fabric in place with sub-centimeter precision.  But if you had a tailor who was fussing over sub-millimeter alterations in the length of your trousers (“the pin is between the wrong fibers!”), you would have an emotional reaction to him and leave the shop.  If your trousers came back from the tailor 10 cm too long or 10 cm too short, you would likewise have an emotional reaction and leave the shop.

The millimeter digit is the first insignificant digit in the length of a pair of trousers: you would possibly be annoyed if the centimeter digit were wrong, but probably not notice if the millimeter digit were wrong.  So for my trousers, 110 cm has three significant digits.

Of course, you might be shorter than I am, and your trousers might only be 95 cm long. Do your trousers only have  two significant figures?  If I decree “trousers have three significant figures,” have I doomed short people to a world filled with insane submillimeter tailors?  No.  Trust your intuition, keep an extra digit if you feel squashy about rounding too much, and be aware that there are more robust ways than counting significant figures for people who really need to be sure about their uncertainty analysis.

Comment: [Anger management previously](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185237/44126).

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it becomes $4\times10^8$, not $400000000$. It seems pointless because you are thinking of exact numbers in your example, and if every number in there was an exact number it would be pointless. But in real life at least some of those numbers are going to come from measurements and measurements have uncertainty.

Basically, you do not write down digits that may not be true. Another more explicit method of expressing uncertainty is writing down the error bars like $3\pm0.1$ but even there the fact that $0.1$ was written instead of $0.10$ holds significance.

Significant digits is sort of an implicit way of expressing and interpreting uncertainty when there is nothing explicit to express uncertainty to keep things in check.

If your 3 is a factor of three (exact) then you don't need to round significant digits because it is *exactly* 3; In other words $3.\bar0$.

But if your 3 is actually a measurement like 3 meters then there is uncertainy in that number. Since you do not write digits you are not sure about and all you wrote down was $3m$ that means the actual number could be anywhere between $3.\bar0$m and $3.\bar9$. If you wrote $3.0$m then that means you were sure of more digits in your measurement and by doing that you are saying the real number is somewhere between $3.\bar0m$ and $3.0\bar9$m

So if we assume that 123456789 is an exact number in your example (or is a measurement accurate to that number of digits) if we multiply them together, then the actual answer could be anywhere between $370 370 367.\bar0$ and $493 827 156.\bar0$

Between 123456789 and 3, the 3 has the most uncertainty in it because it has the least significant digits (the digits you are sure about) therefore it is the weakest link holding back the your calculation. The result of the calculation can't be any more accurate than the 3 is so we use the same number of significant digits in the result.

That is why you cannot say the answer is 400000000, because if you did that would mean you are certain about every zero in that result because that's what you wrote down. Since you are not sure of all those zeroes, you can only say the answer is $4\times10^8$, which as written means the result could be anywhere between $4\times10^8$ and $4.\bar9\times10^8$

Comment: I'm used to the convention that something like "3m" is treated as the result of rounding so for the actual length x, 2.5m <= x < 3.5m.

Comment: I believe that the least count is kept in mind while writing uncertain digit. E.g. 3m =2.9m or 3.1m. so why there is 3m= 3.0 to 3.9 in your answer?

Comment: @Jasper I think there are different schemes because as someone basically said in the comments: significant digits are kind of a sloppy way to handle things. Maybe they should be considered a lie to children to make them more aware of what they are writing down.

Comment: @user359206 That could be true and would make a bit more sense. But it can also depends on the way your measuring instrument works too. There's a lot of different ways to go about things.

Comment: Mathematically $4\times10^8 =400000000$.

Comment: @md2perpe But we're not talking about mathematically, we're talking about numbers obtained from the real world.

Comment: @DKNguyen. Still, it's the same number.

Comment: @md2perpe I can only assume you are being facetious because anyone who has something to contribute to this thread should know that they do not have the same meaning as far as precision is concerned. A measurement of 4×10^8 is *not* the same as a measurement of 400000000.

Comment: @DKNguyen. Thanks for teaching me a new word, _facetious_! Actually, I'm serious. **user359206** is correct that if $370\ 370\ 367$ is *rounded* to 1 significant figure then the result is $400\ 000\ 000.$ Rounding gives an exact number, not an interval.

Comment: Actually I did not use point at the end because that increases the precision. Eg.100 = 1sig fig, 100. =3 sig figs so 40000000=4×10⁸ both LHS and RHS have 1 sig fig.

Comment: @user359206 That's not how significant figures are written. Zero doesn't get any special treatment in something like 40000000. Your interpretation would mean that something like 4000000 is 1 sigdig but 4100000 is two sig digs or 4123456 is 7 sig digs.

Comment: Yes that is the thing that I know so far from book resources. Book maybe wrong I don't know but that is the reference I used here. But the logic there was that changing unit of measurement doesn't affect the sig fig. E.g. 4m has 1 sig fig and 4m=400cm=4000 mm would also have 1sig fig.

Comment: @user359206 I looked around a bit and I found some examples that seem to imply that is one interpretation. But, regardless, I find it extremely sloppy because if you interpret sigdigs that way, then you might as well not care about sig digs at all because it no longer represents precision.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the error one might have while conducting measurements is large. Then, you do not need to be performing calculations with accuracy larger than the one allowed by the experimental device. This is the point, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Play with this *Rounding Significant Figures Calculator*, and you will understand.  https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/significant-figures-rounding.php

You will have to provide the *number of significant figures* you want to round to.
In your example you rounded to one significant figure.

If you round to four significant figures for example, you will get 370400000 So you will get the first four most significant figures and the rest will be zero. The last significant figure will be rounded: ...37.... will be rounded to ...40....

The number of significant figures you need depends on the application.

If for example, that number is an amount in your bank account, then you want to know it to the last dollar, so you may not want to round at all.

If instead, you are looking at the speed of light trying to get a grasp on its magnitude, then two or three significant figures are enough.
Thousands separators will help, as in 299,000,000 m/s.
This particular example cries for even more rounding, to 300,000,000 m/s or better 300,000 km/s

Answer (score 2):

The concept of significant digits is used when working with measured numbers as opposed to exact numbers.
It is a relatively simple way to determine how precisely you will know the result of a calculation involving measured numbers.

Say your numbers $3$ and $123456789$ come from measuring lengths by using a method that that has a precision of one unit.  Perhaps you're pacing to measure length and you can measure to the nearest metre. The product of $3$ m and $123456789$ m might represent an area in square metres.

The thing is, if you are only measuring to the lengths to the nearest metre then the length you recorded as $3$ m is almost certainly not *exactly* three metres.  The actual length might be anywhere between $2.5$ m and $3.5$ m.  Similarly the other length could be up to half a metre more or less, though as percentage uncertainty this is much, much less important.
So the actual area could be anywhere from $2.5 \times 123456788.5 = 3.1 \times 10^8$ to $3.5 \times 123456789.5 = 4.3 \times 10^8$.  So, if you only know the shorter length to one significant digit, you would not be able to claim to know the area to the nearest square metre i.e. to nine significant digits.  Rounding off to one significant digit, i.e. $400000000$, expresses what the calculated product is and also how precisely you know it.  It may look like you are introducing a large error in the product, and you would be if you knew the two initial numbers exactly, but if they are measured values then $370370367$ is almost certainly not the correct product.

There are more sophisticated methods of error analysis.

Comment: I'm sure you know this but the way your text is written basically implies that writing $3$m means $3m\pm0.5m$ which is not true. It's an alternate and more explicit approach to expressing the uncertainty than significant digits. Using significant digits for uncertainty $3m$ is more kind of the default way when there is nothing else mentioned so things don't unknowingly go out of control.

Answer (score 0):

Your example can be useful as an exercise in rounding, but is not a good example of how significant figures are used.

A more typical example is a simple electrical circuit with a battery and a resistor. You find the voltage over the resistor be $U = 7.23\ \mathrm{V}$ and the current be $I = 1.37\ \mathrm{mA}$. You use Ohm's law to calculate the resistance and enter the values into your calculator getting
$$
R = \frac{U}{I} = \frac{7.23\ \mathrm{V}}{1.37\ \mathrm{mA}} = 5.277372262\ \mathrm{k\Omega}
$$
Then you realize that the calculator has rounded or truncated the value and there is in fact an infinite number of decimals. This makes you wonder how many decimals you should write down. So you start thinking...

After a while you realize that also the Volt and Ampere meters have rounded the values. The real voltage is something between $7.225$ and $7.235\ \mathrm{V},$ and the real current is something between $1.365$ and $1.375\ \mathrm{mA}.$ Therefore the true resistance is something between
$$
R_\text{min} = \frac{U_\text{min}}{I_\text{max}} = \frac{7.225\ \mathrm{V}}{1.375\ \mathrm{mA}} = 5.254545454\ldots\ \mathrm{k\Omega}
$$
and
$$
R_\text{max} = \frac{U_\text{max}}{I_\text{min}} = \frac{7.235\ \mathrm{V}}{1.365\ \mathrm{mA}} = 5.300366300\ldots\ \mathrm{k\Omega}.
$$
Obviously it's hardly meaningful to write more than one decimal: $5.3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$ to which both $R_\text{min}$ and $R_\text{max}$ can be rounded. But the value is probably close to the mean value of $R_\text{min}$ and $R_\text{max},$ which is $5.27745587\ldots\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$ and which is quite close to what you calculated first. So perhaps $5.28\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$ is a good answer...? Or as an interval, e.g. a mean value and an error: $5.28\pm 0.023\ \mathrm{k\Omega}$?

It has become a practice to round the result to the minimum number of significant figures among the input values. It's a *rule of thumb*, not a mathematically exact rule. In real science a more rigorous analysis should be made.

In the given example, both input values have three significant figures so the rule says that we should use that also for the result, i.e. the answer should be given as $5.28\ \mathrm{k\Omega}.$

Comment: What if I measure the volume of a cube of length=9cm. How sig fig is going to produce some good answer. I believe the answer would be 729cm³, while using sig fig it would be 700cm³. Are both acceptable?

Comment: @user359206. How big is the error in your measure of the cube side length? Do you think that it's $0.5\ \mathrm{cm}$? I don't think so. Probably it's rather $0.05\ \mathrm{cm}$ (half a millimeter). That means that you have 2 significant figures and should answer with $730\ \mathrm{cm}^3.$